# Where to buy Schengen insurance in Istanbul?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, insurance, istanbul

I am in Istanbul (but not Turkish citizen) and want to apply for a Schengen visa. A mandatory document for the visa application is travel insurance valid for Schengen states.

Where can I buy the travel insurance in Istanbul?

I asked here (before local travel agencies) to avoid possible rip-off. It is great if you guide me where is the best place to buy it.

Comment: (+1) You might also consider buying it online.

Comment: You can get it online; here for example: `https://www.axa-schengen.com`

Comment: Some banks offer insurance packages for travellers, check with yours

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to buy it online and compare the different prices that different companies offer. So you can find the cheapest one. You can also buy it online via aircraft companies. I once, purchased from the website of Pegasus Airlines (flypgs.com) but I do not know if you need a ticket purchased from them or is it available for anyone. Turkish Airlines also offer this service but it might be a little expensive (I guess)